# Region Inside DataTamplate is not registered. How to do it

Tags: prism, prism-4, prism-5

I want to create a region inside the DataTemplate. My requirement is, after Injecting views in TabControl, lets says Tab A, Tab B, Tab C. After that I want to create a region inside a Tab A, so that I can injecting the views inside Tab A. Means in button click, I can inject a view inside the StackPanel region. Please help me out.

```
<ContentControl >
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ChildRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionManager="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource ObservableRegionManager}}">
                <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Text="View A" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="48"></TextBlock>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}},             
                       Path=DataContext.NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="ViewB">Navigate ViewB in Scoped Region</Button>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

I applied the below suggestion still not getting any success.

http://southworks.com/blog/2011/11/10/regions-inside-datatemplates-in-prism-v4-using-a-region-behavior/

Throwing error views not registered.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, using Regions inside of DataTemplates is not supported in Prism.  Since you are using a custom solution to achieve this, it will be difficult to help, especially since you have not posted any of the code.  Due to the nature of extending Prism, even if you did post some code it would most likely not help anyone diagnose your issue.

My suggestion is to not use DataTemplate that contain regions.  I wouldn't use DataTemplate to represent entire views anyways, with or without regions.

I suggest you watch this course:

https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/prism-mastering-tabcontrol/table-of-contents

This should help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your  suggestions  Brian. Even I am ok without DataTemplate. But my requirement is . Initially I need to inject views in TabItem by view discovery. After that with in tabItem I want to navigate through multiple views. But each and every time the view is not registered i:e not found. Even if you want i will post my code in Github.  I watched almost all of your course, awesome tutorial Brain :)  Thanks for replay.

Comment: Put your sample on github.  I am not going to debug your custom code, but rather just your initial setup to make sure it is correct.